# What is web service composition?

Tags: web-services, composition

What exactly is web service composition?

Comment: is google broken on your PC?

Comment: nope it aint. google just got me to this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composition refers to the way something is build, the new term at the moment is mash-up which basically means utilising a variety of different services in a composite application.  So that functionality of disparate application can be used in one application.

I think your referring to service granularity - which means how much functionality a service exposes. a coarse grained service will expose a whole process as a consumable unit whereas a fine grained service will expose a specific unit of logic from a larger process.  Obviously, it is up to the service architects to determine what granularity of service works best in the given environment.

This also, in a way has to do with the style of SOAP message you are using whether it is RPC style or document and that a service should be atomic and not hold external state.  Meaning it does not need to know any more information other than that in the SOAP message to perform its function.

Hope this gives you a good starting point.  The trouble with service-orientation is that it differs depending on who you read, but the main points stay the same!

Jon

Answer (score 1):

Some web services which are provided for clients are abstract and composition of some smaller web services and it's called **web service composition**.

Sometimes there are more than one web service in order to use as the mentioned small web services, so we choose them based on QoS (Quality of Service) and many researches have been done on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Web service composition involves integration of two or more web service to achieve more added value of business functionality. A work flow composer is responsible of aggregating different web services to act as a single service according to functional requirements as well as QoS constrains. BPEL is one of the popular composers uses XML language to perform service composition.  Fine-grained  services perform single business task and provides higher flexibility and reusability. However, coarse-grained service involves performing complex business functionality leading to lower flexibility